# How to stop SNMP from running automatically on Windows boot

Tags: windows-ce, snmp

I would like to stop SNMP from starting with Windows (WinCE 6.0 x86).  I would then like to load it later at my convenience.

Currently my registry settings are as follows, I tried `Flags=4` but that didnt work either, neither does `Keep=0`. ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee500226.aspx)).

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SNMP]
    ;"Flags"=dword:4
    "Keep"=dword:0
```

With these settings SNMP doesn't load but, if I then try to load it later, it fails with the error code `0` (helpful I know).  This occurs whether I try to load the service by a call to `ActivateService` and by loading it via cmd line.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to get this working?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This registry setting seemed to do the trick

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SNMP]
    "Flags"=dword:14
```